# Delete some pushed commits after rebasing

Tags: git, rebase

In doing some git rebasing I got myself twisted around. In the graph below I want `stable` to point at commit `6016f6` and I want all the other commits "above" `6016f6` to go away.  In other words, I have the `BEFORE` but I want the `AFTER`:

**BEFORE:**

```
*   commit 725b5f (origin/fixpaths)
|\  Merge: 6016f65 e91c3aa
| | Date:   Sat Apr 27 07:04:05 2013 -0700
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'fixpaths' of wayfare.example.org:/modules/base into fixpaths
| |   
| * commit e91c3a
| | Date:   Fri Apr 26 16:49:39 2013 -0700
| | 
| |     fix permissions on many cron files
 .
 .
 .
| * commit 160460
| | Date:   Fri Apr 26 14:35:14 2013 -0700
| | 
| |     module paths cleanup for dns.pp
| |   
| * commit ecbfd6
| | Date:   Fri Apr 26 14:23:30 2013 -0700
| | 
| |     fix module paths in cron base module
| |   
* | commit 6016f6 (HEAD, fixpaths)
|/  Date:   Fri Apr 26 14:23:30 2013 -0700
|   
|       Change module paths to work with base module.
|  
* commit 88d0bc (origin/stable, stable)
| Date:   Mon Apr 22 15:51:44 2013 -0700
| 
|     committing everything for branch stable
|    
| * commit 9baf5a (tag: release/latest, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
|/  Date:   Wed Apr 24 14:47:23 2013 -0700
|   
|       Fix permissions on all of the cron jobs
```

**AFTER:**

```
*   commit 6016f6 (HEAD, stable, origin/stable)
|/  Date:   Fri Apr 26 14:23:30 2013 -0700
|   
|       Change module paths to work with base module.
|  
* commit 88d0bc
| Date:   Mon Apr 22 15:51:44 2013 -0700
| 
|     committing everything for branch stable
|    
| * commit 9baf5a (tag: release/latest, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
|/  Date:   Wed Apr 24 14:47:23 2013 -0700
|   
|       Fix permissions on all of the cron jobs
```

(Note: to save some space I have truncated the hashes and removed the Author line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the hard part - envisioning what you want the tree to look like.  Now just move the branch markers around to match it:

```
$ # Move 'stable' branch marker up
$ git checkout stable
$ git merge --ff-only 6016f65
$ git push origin stable
```

Now, what to do about 'fixpaths' - either pull back the remote 'fixpaths' to match your local  (2 ways below) or just delete the local and remote branches because you are done with it (last way below):

```
$ # Delete the remote fixpaths and repush the local one
$ git push origin :fixpaths
$ git push origin fixpaths

$ # Force the remote 'fixpaths' branch marker backward to your local 'fixpaths'
$ # (Note: generally push -f is inadvisable unless you understand what you are doing)
$ git push -f origin fixpaths

$ # Or else delete fixpaths because you don't need it anymore
$ # Caution: this will 'delete' the local and remote branches
$ git branch -d fixpaths
$ git push origin :fixpaths
```

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout stable`, `git cherry-pick 6016f6`.  Just cherry-pick that extra commit onto the `stable` branch, and you'll be set, if I understand correctly.